# How to isolate two containers connected to the same bridge?

Tags: iptables, firewall, bridge, lxc

I have several [LXD containers](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/03/14/lxd-2-0-introduction-to-lxd/) which are bound to a single bridge (the default `lxdbr0` or another one, it does not matter). The host itself has another two interfaces, one ultimately connecting it to Internet and another one to which a WiFi AP is attached.

The data flows are orchestrated by [Shorewall](http://shorewall.net/) (which builds the appropriate `iptable` rules).

The restrictions I put in place work fine for traffic between the containers to Internet or to the AP network (and between the AP network and Internet). **The problem I have is that inter-container traffic does not seem to be affected by the `iptable` rules.** Even with a plain `REJECT` policy for the container IP, I still manage to ping the IP of another container (and nothing else, including its own gateway - which is expected).

My understanding is that the bridge itself works on ISO/OSI layer 2. In that case firewalling would not affect the traffic.

At the same time, it has an IP, which is the gateway for the containers (the containers all have an address from the same `10.20.30.0/24` network, `10.20.30.254` being the IP of the bridge). Since this is now layer 3 communication, shouldn't the traffic go though `iptables`?

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found a solution?

Comment: @LotoLo: I have moved to systemd-nspawn and firehol in the meantime but as far as I remember I ended up using ebtables (http://ebtables.netfilter.org/) which are the equivalent of iptables for L2 traffic. If I was to do it today I would probably use nftables (https://wiki.nftables.org/) which combine more and are more future-proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a bridge, use *router* mode in the lxc networking. A bridge connects all the veth NICs attached to it together, by design, as if it were a physical network hub.

If you create the NICs in the containers like this.

```
lxc.net.0.veth.pair = vethXX
lxc.net.0.veth.mode = router
```

each NIC is independant.

Each container needs its own subnet, typcially lxc containers share 10.0.3.X  but in this mode you need a subnet per container.

Now you can route traffic as if the veth interfaces were physical NICs and nftables firewall will work, if you do want to allow traffic between containers for something specific.

Traffic between lxc like this can be filtered with the *forward* chain

```
table ip filter {
    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy drop; # defailt to block everything
                    
        # allow only what you want, e.g. ping
        icmp type echo-request accept
        icmp type echo-reply accept
    }
}
```

You can turn off the `lxcbr0` bridge if you use router mode.

Answer (score 0):

Not an ideal answer if you have lot of containers but you can use the [shorewall hosts](http://shorewall.net/manpages/shorewall-hosts.html) file with an entry for each host, ie with a /32 network like this:

/etc/shorewall/interfaces:

```
#ZONE  INTERFACE   OPTIONS
...
lxc    lxc-br0     ...,routeback,bridge
```

/etc/shorewall/zones:

```
#ZONE       TYPE       OPTIONS         IN          OUT
fw          firewall
lxc         ipv4
lxc12:lxc   ipv4
```

/etc/shorewall/hosts:

```
#ZONE     HOSTS                              OPTIONS
lxc12     lxc-br0:192.168.0.12/32
```

/etc/shorewall/rules:

```
######################################################################################################################################################################################################
#ACTION         SOURCE          DEST            PROTO   DEST    SOURCE          ORIGINAL        RATE            USER/   MARK    CONNLIMIT       TIME            HEADERS         SWITCH          HELPER
#                                                       PORT    PORT(S)         DEST            LIMIT           GROUP
#Allow host web server to proxy requests to the container
Web(ACCEPT)     $FW     lxc12
```